# Wordpress rewrite API, add_rewrite_rule issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed wordpress in my local machine:
So my home_url is http://localhost/wordpress (Have not created any virtual host entry)

I have created a page named test with page_id = 19. Now  I need to use the rewrite as following:

when there will be any request as http://localhost/wordpress/group/abc, 
It should be converted to http://localhost/wordpress/?page_id=19&group=abc

My .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

# END WordPress

What I tried:

```
 add_action('init', function() {
     global $wp_rewrite; 
     $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
     add_rewrite_rule('^group/([^/]+)', 'index.php?page_id=19&group=abc', 'top');
    add_rewrite_tag('%group%', '[A-Za-z]+');
 });
```

But whenever I am trying to access http://localhost/wordpress/group/abc I am getting 404 error.

Please suggest, am I doing any wrong .

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you saved permalinks to refresh rewite rules?

Comment: @batz, yes I had tried this already to debug, changing the add_rewrite_rule and saving the permlink. But it didn't work out.

Comment: page id probably should be post_id?

Comment: @David in wordpress all the examples were p=19 but as it was not working so I tried with page_id. But still no result. With your suggestion  I tried post_id, still no result.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot resaerch found this:

- It is always safe to use pagename instead of page_id.
- The custom query vars (here group) used should be registered.
- Also there is a filter named [rewrite_rules_array](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/rewrite_rules_array%22rewrite_rules_array%22)

So the above code might look like (added page name is test):

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', function($query_vars) {
   $query_vars[] = 'group';
   return $query_vars;
});

add_action('init', function() {
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    add_rewrite_rule('group/(.*)', 'index.php?pagename=test&group=$matches[1]', 'top');
});
```

But we can not access the group value via `$_GET['group']`. we need to access it via `get_query_var('group')`

Another method of adding rewrite rule:

```
add_action( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'rewrite_rules' );
function rewrite_rules( $rules ) {   
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules[ 'group/(.*)/?$' ] = 'index.php?pagename=test&group=$matches[1]';
    return $newrules + $rules;
}
```